# There is no package called ‘farver’

Tags: r

I keep getting this error message, I don't know how to fix that. I have downloaded the latest version of R & RStudio.

Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘farver’

Comment: `install.packages('farver')` ?

Comment: This might help if you're new to R https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-packages-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
install.packages('farver')
```

You can also try:

```
install.packages("farver", dependencies=T)
```